# Cannot mount external hard drive after using Clonezilla

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, mount

Linux Mint 17 Qiana 64-bit. Cinnamon.

Yesterday I tried to back up my internal (where Linux resides) hard drive's image to my external USB hard drive using Clonezilla. Last month this operation went successfully and the external USB drive is nearly brand new. But this time, the operation failed at the end where Clonezilla checks the saved image for restorability, I got some I/O errors I didn't write down or note. Now, after rebooting I cannot access my external drive. I see it's icon but when I click it to mount I get this:

[image]

My external drive is NTFS formatted since I used to use Windows before. Do I need to do an equivalent of scan and repair file system on it? If so what utility would I use?

Comment: The error message suggests using `chkdsk /f` from Windows then rebooting twice. You could try that first from a Windows repair console (if you have the disk, or can repair from Windows bootloader to repair console), then reboot 2 times. Otherwise *nix you can use `fsck` or `e2fsck`, from a live environment, or recovery from option on GRUB entry. MAN links: [fsck] (http://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck), [e2fsck] (http://linux.die.net/man/8/e2fsck)

Comment: Is this the same external hard drive that you used successfully last month?

Comment: Looks like the drive is dead.  Check `dmesg` or /var/log/syslog for more detailed error messages.

Comment: @Mark Plotnick Yes.